# JavaFX combobox, on item clicked

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

My problem is as follows,

For the sake of this question I reproduced the problem in a new project.

Say I have this application with a combobox in it, there could be 1 or more items in there. And I would like it to be so that when the user clicks an item in the combobox that 'something' happens.

I produced the following code:

```
        obsvList.add("item1");

        cbTest.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Item clicked");
            }
        });
```

This works when the application starts and an item is selected for the first time. This also works when there are 2 or more items in the combobox (when the user clicks item 1, then item 2, then item 1 for example)

However my problem is that when there is only 1 item in the combobox, let's say "item1". And the user reopens the combobox and clicks "item1" again then it won't redo the action.

[image]

It will only print the line "Item Clicked" when a 'new' item is clicked.

I hope it made it clear what the problem i'm experiencing is, if not please ask for clarification and I will give so where needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You use the Control itself and not its items !

Comment: That sounds more like the behavior of a menu than the behavior of a combo box. Wouldn't it be better to use a [`MenuButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html)? (The functionality of a combo box is to make "selections". The functionality of a menu (or menu button) is to present a set of "commands" to the user. What you are describing is more like commands than selections.)

Comment: @James_D Hm, a menuButton looks really interesting, I will see if I can implement it without too many problems

Comment: @James_D Let's say I'm making this bank application, the user starts with 1 bankaccount, and could choose to add more later, and when the user selects a bankaccount from the combobox I'd like to load the specifics for that account (amount of money left, etc) does a menuitem still work best for that scenario?

Comment: OK, that sounds like selection. In that case it doesn't make sense to perform any action when the user "reselects" the same option. If the user selects "option 1", you display the details for "option 1". If the user then selects the same option again, there is nothing to do because those details are already displayed. If you do something else that causes those details not to be displayed, then you should make sure the combo box displays a different option when that happens (else your UI is effectively in an inconsistent state).

Comment: @James_D The point of "reselecting the same item" is for "refreshing" purposes, in the time after the user clicked it for the first time, the details could have been chaged, And I would like them to 'refresh'. Of course I could just add another button with "refresh" on it that reloads the details. But I'd like it more design-wise if it works within 1 combobox

Comment: IMHO needing a "refresh" is a sign that your application is badly designed. Just make sure that either the application automatically refreshes, or at least warns the user if the data is (or may be) stale and give them a separate option to refresh in that case. Even an individual "refresh" button is better than using a selection-type control to implement refresh (again, jmo).

Comment: Updated answer with more details....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functionality of a combo box is to present the user with a list of options from which to choose. When you are using a control which implies selection, you should really ensure that the UI is always consistent with the option that is selected. If you do this, then it makes no sense to "repeat an action" when the user "reselects" the same option (because the UI is already in the required state). One approach to this is to use binding or listeners on the combo box's value:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ComboBox<Item> choices = new ComboBox<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <=3 ; i++) {
            choices.getItems().add(new Item("Choice "+i, "These are the details for choice "+i));
        }

        Label label = new Label();

        choices.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
            label.textProperty().unbind();
            if (newItem == null) {
                label.setText("");
            } else {
                label.textProperty().bind(newItem.detailsProperty());
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(label);
        root.setTop(choices);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public class Item {
        private final String name ;
        private final StringProperty details = new SimpleStringProperty() ;

        public Item(String name, String details) {
            this.name = name ;
            setDetails(details) ;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name ;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }

        public final StringProperty detailsProperty() {
            return this.details;
        }


        public final String getDetails() {
            return this.detailsProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setDetails(final String details) {
            this.detailsProperty().set(details);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In this case, there is never a need to repeat an action when the user "reselects" the same option, because the code always assures that the UI is consistent with what is selected anyway (there is necessarily nothing to do if the user selects the option that is already selected). By using bindings in the part of the UI showing the details (just a simple label in this case), we are assured that the UI stays up to date if the data changes externally. (Obviously in a real application, this may be far more complex, but the basic strategy is still exactly the same.)

On the other hand, functionality that requires an action to be repeated if the user selects the same functionality is better considered as presenting the user with a set of "actions". The appropriate controls for this are things like menus, toolbars with buttons, and [`MenuButton`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html).

An example of a set of repeatable actions is:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MenuButtonExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton("Items");
        Label label = new Label();

        Item[] items = new Item[3];
        for (int i = 1 ; i <=3 ; i++) {
            items[i-1] = new Item("Item "+i);
        }

        for (Item item : items) {
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(item.getName());
            menuItem.setOnAction(e -> item.setTimesChosen(item.getTimesChosen() + 1));
            menuButton.getItems().add(menuItem);
        }

        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> 
            Stream.of(items)
                .map(item -> String.format("%s chosen %d times", item.getName(), item.getTimesChosen()))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")), 
            Stream.of(items)
                .map(Item::timesChosenProperty)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new IntegerProperty[0])));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(label);
        root.setTop(menuButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final String name ;
        private final IntegerProperty timesChosen = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Item(String name) {
            this.name = name ;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name ;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }

        public final IntegerProperty timesChosenProperty() {
            return this.timesChosen;
        }


        public final int getTimesChosen() {
            return this.timesChosenProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setTimesChosen(final int timesChosen) {
            this.timesChosenProperty().set(timesChosen);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read my comment under the main question, would you suggest a menubutton to be a good alternative in a scenario like that too?

Comment: Hey thanks for this great answer, for now I used a MenuButton to achieve what I wanted, but as you said i should look in rethinking what I actually want and how to achieve this.

Comment: @James_D Let's say the user clicks on the combobox and then sees/realizes that he already have the correct option selected so he clicks on it again. Shouldn't it just close the displayed listview instead of doing nothing. Let's that is the behavior we are looking for, what would you suggest?

Comment: @JawadElFou  Not sure I understand your point. That’s the default behaviour of a combo box; the `valueProperty` would not change in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to set a listener on the ListView pane, that appears whenever you click on the ComboBox. The ListView instance is created once the ComboBox is first loaded in the JavaFX scene. Therefore, we add a listener on the ComboBox to check when it appears on the scene, and then through the "lookup" method we get the ListView and add a listener to it.

```
private EventHandler<MouseEvent> cboxMouseEventHandler;

private void initComboBox() {
    ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    comboBox.getItems().add("Item 1");
    comboBox.getItems().add("Item 2");
    comboBox.getItems().add("Item 3");

    comboBox.sceneProperty().addListener((a,oldScene,newScene) -> {
        if(newScene == null || cboxMouseEventHandler != null)
            return;
            
        ListView<?> listView = (ListView<?>) comboBox.lookup(".list-view");
        if(listView != null) {
            cboxMouseEventHandler = (e) -> {
                Platform.runLater(()-> {
                    String selectedValue = (String) listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                    if(selectedValue.equals("Item 1"))
                        System.out.println("Item 1 clicked");
                });
            }; // cboxMouseEventHandler
        
            listView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, cboxMouseEventHandler); 
        } // if
    });
} // initComboBox
```